# SwiftUI: Broken explicit animations in NavigationView?

Tags: animation, swiftui

When I put an explicit animation inside a NavigationView, as an undesirable side effect, it animates the initial layout of the NavigationView content. It gets especially bad with infinite animations. Is there a way to disable this side effect?

Example: the image below is supposed to be an animated red loader on a full screen blue background. Instead I get this infinite loop of a scaling blue background:

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct EscapingAnimationTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                EscapingAnimationTest_Inner()
                Spacer()
            }
            .backgroundFill(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}

struct EscapingAnimationTest_Inner: View {
    @State var degrees: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.0, to: 0.3)
            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: degrees))
            .onAppear() {
                withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                    degrees = 360
                }
            }
    }
}

struct EscapingAnimationTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EscapingAnimationTest()
    }
}
```

Comment: Every example I can find uses onAppear, which suffers from this obviously crippling problem. I used .task as suggested by @Hollycene below instead, which is tidy and effective.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here is fixed part ([another my answer with explanations is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66643096/12299030)).

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
struct EscapingAnimationTest_Inner: View {
    @State var degrees: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.0, to: 0.3)
            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(degrees)))
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: degrees)
            .onAppear() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {   // << here !!
                    degrees = 360
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Update:** the same will be using `withAnimation`

```
.onAppear() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
           degrees = 360
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. You changed it to implicit animation. I want to keep explicit animation.

Comment: It is explicit, because linked to value.

Comment: My bad, i missed that final "value" param in .animation() method. Both of your solutions work, thank you!

BTW, do you have any idea why in my original code explicit animation was initiating NavigationView animation? Conceptually it shouldn't. Is this a bug?

Comment: Do you know why wrapping `withAnimation` in `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` resolves the issue?

Comment: @TylerPashigian You actually don't need to wrap `withAnimation` with`DispatchQueue.main.async {}`. My code works without it.

Comment: I had the same issue and wrapping in DispatchQueue.main.async helped me. But I really want to know why and how it works :)

Comment: Worked for me too. But I'm in the same boat as @badadin, and really curious: Does anyone know why simply wrapping with `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` makes things work?

Comment: @TylerPashigian and others, it is separation of constructions in different run loop events.

Comment: This feels like Android's `post` method (either on View or on a Handler)

Comment: Man, SwiftUI got a long way to go. Sad.

Comment: I feel like this is an issue specifically with NavigationView's but I'm not sure. I'm also trying to write a wrapper around withAnimation(...) function to always jump on the main thread but it's returning an implicit `Result` type and when I jump on the main inside the function, that's not working

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem to yours, but with `NavigationStack` on iOS 17. Although the proposed solution, using `DispatchQueue` as suggested in the accepted answer, worked for me, I discovered that the same effect can be achieved by using the `task{}` modifier instead of `onAppear{}`.

```
struct EscapingAnimationTest_Inner: View {
    @State var degrees: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.0, to: 0.3)
            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(degrees)))
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: degrees)
            .task { // -> use task instead of onAppear
                // no need for DispatchQueue.main.async
                degrees = 360
            }
    }
}
```

This allows you to avoid using DispatchQueue, making the overall solution more "SwiftUI-like".  Nevertheless, I welcome any suggestions or improvements.

Comment: This is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Using `DispatchQueue.main.async` before outside of the `withAnimation` blocks worked for me but this code didn't look very clean.
I found another (and in my opinion cleaner) solution which is this:

- Create a `isAnimating` variable outside of the body

```
@State var isAnimating = false
```

Then at the end of your outer VStack, set this variable to true inside `onAppear`. Then call `rotationEffect` with isAnimating ternary operator and then clal .animation() after. Here is the full code:

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // the trick is to use .animation and some helper variables
            Circle()
               .trim(from: 0.0, to: 0.3)
               .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
               .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isAnimating ? 360 : 0))
               .animation(Animation.linear(duration:1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: isAnimating)
        } //: VStack
        .onAppear {
            isAnimating = true
        }
    }
```

This way you don't need to use DispatchQueue.main.async.