# How to have an view as background SwiftUI without strange looking movements?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hi guys I basically have the issue with my background. I made an animated background look in a different SwiftUI file and I want it to be shown as a background in another view. Can you please help me do that?

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnimatedBackground: View {
    var itemsPerRow = 6
    @State var isAnimating = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            ForEach(0..<getNumberOfRows()){i in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<self.itemsPerRow){j in
                        Image(self.getImage(indexLocation: (i * self.itemsPerRow) + j)).resizable().padding()
                        
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/CGFloat(self.itemsPerRow), height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/CGFloat(self.itemsPerRow))
                            .opacity(self.isAnimating ? 1 : 0)
                            .animation(
                                Animation
                                    .linear(duration: Double.random(in: 1.0...2.0))
                                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                                    .delay(Double.random(in: 0...1.5))
                            
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(){
                self.isAnimating = true
        }
    }
    
    func getImage(indexLocation:Int) -> String{
        let totalNumbersOfAssets = 30
        print(indexLocation % 30)
        return String(indexLocation % 30)
    }
    
    func getNumberOfRows() -> Int {
        let heightPerItem = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/CGFloat(self.itemsPerRow)
        return Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.height/heightPerItem) + 1
    }
}

struct AnimatedBackground_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnimatedBackground()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code so far?

Comment: I tried 10 mins to add my code to here bu I couldn't. Can you please tell me how to do it it always give error of code line.

Comment: Just copy and paste it into your question. Before the first line, add 3 ``` marks. If the formatting is weird it's fine, we can edit it.

Comment: @aheze I did it. Thanks man waiting for your reply :)

Comment: @aheze I want to have this view as a background view to another page. Thats what I mean.

Comment: We solved this over Discord. For future reference, the solution was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566492/swiftui-broken-explicit-animations-in-navigationview/64566746#64566746

Answer (score 0):

Just add it with `background()`:

```
var body: some View {
        Text("hi")
            .font(.system(.title))
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(AnimatedBackground())
        
    }
```

I've chosen to add it on a `Text` view here, but you can apply `background()` to any view.

In the event that you want everything to happen at the same rate (as you maybe are implying in the comments), you can move the `.animation` outside of your `ForEach` statements:

```
var body: some View {
       VStack(spacing: 0){
           ForEach(0..<getNumberOfRows()){i in
               HStack(spacing: 0) {
                   ForEach(0..<self.itemsPerRow){j in
                       Image(self.getImage(indexLocation: (i * self.itemsPerRow) + j)).resizable().padding()
                       
                           .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/CGFloat(self.itemsPerRow), height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/CGFloat(self.itemsPerRow))
                           
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       .opacity(self.isAnimating ? 1 : 0)
       .animation(
           Animation
               .linear(duration: Double.random(in: 1.0...2.0))
               .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
               .delay(Double.random(in: 0...1.5))
       
       )
       .onAppear(){
               self.isAnimating = true
       }
   }
```

Comment: I did it but the icons moving all around and not doing what I want.

Comment: What I want is to make icons stay where thy are and animate which I described in the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You asked in the question how to use your view as a background, which this (and the other answer) show. If you have a question about how to change your animation, I'd need a more clear explanation of what you're looking for.  As far as I can tell, the icons are staying where they are.

Comment: You are right. Thats the actual answer. This view in its canvas is working so good. Icons which I put is not moving anywhere. but when I tell  .background(AnimatedBackground()) this one the icons are start moving all around the screen. But it should stay and just blur and get clear by time I described.

Comment: Are you saying you want all of the images to change opacity at the same time at the same pace instead of all differently?

Comment: Lemme send you a video of what I want. can you please send me your email or anything that I can send you info needed. Because its to hard to explain it here.

Comment: You can dm me on Twitter (@jnpdx) if you want, but it's good for other learners to keep everything visible here on SO.  Check the code I added first and see if it addresses what you're looking for.

Comment: @CanxeOfficial you can dm me on Discord (aheze#3125) if you want, too

Comment: @aheze I have sent a friend request CanXE#2694

Answer (score 0):

So you want `AnimatedBackground` as the background of some view? You can use a `ZStack`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            AnimatedBackground() /// put it here!
            Text("Hello!")
        }
    }
}
```

Result (ContentView):

[image: Result]

Comment: It's working but not the way I want. The icons moving everywhere around and not staying in the place it should be. Do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: I have imported the swift ui btw I just didn't copy that here

Comment: @CanxeOfficial the icons are staying in place I think. Do you want then the animation to happen from the top left to bottom right or something?

Comment: @aheze : how much memory use take that animation?

Comment: @swiftPunk not sure, but memory shouldn't be a problem

Comment: normally they eat up memory up to 40-60 MB which is kind of ishhh