# SwiftUI Animations: Why is the container view moving? I'm struggling to understand this behavior

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I'm building a simple rotating circle loading animation. I've got the circle rotating but the container view is also moving downward for the duration of the animation. I can't figure out what could be causing this strange behavior.

**Example:**

[image]

The White border is the Parent View `ZStack`. The Red border is a `VStack` that I placed to show this weird animation oddity. The Blue border is a `ZStack` that holds the two `Circle`s that animate.

**Here is the code:**

```
struct CustomLoadingView: View {

  let viewWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5
  let backgroundCircleLineWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.025
  let foregroundCircleLineWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.02

  @State var rotationDegree: Angle = Angle.degrees(0)

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
              .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: backgroundCircleLineWidth))
              .fill(Global.Colors.primary60)
            
            Circle()
              .trim(from: 0, to: 0.15)
              .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 7, lineCap: .round))
              .fill(Global.Colors.secondary50)
              .rotationEffect(self.rotationDegree)
        }
          .frame(width: viewWidth, height: viewWidth)
          .border(Color.blue)
          .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 4.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: rotationDegree)
          .onAppear() {
              self.animateLoader()
          }
    }
      .border(Color.red)
}

   func animateLoader() {
      self.rotationDegree = .degrees(720)
   }
}
```

Any idea as to why this is happening and how I can get it to stop? Thanks.

Comment: couldn't reproduce this. Copied the code and it is not moving for me. Maybe its something else that is causing it to move that was not shown? Xcode 14.0.1, iPhone 14 pro, iOS 16.0

Comment: @sfung3 I thought that could be the case as well. Wouldn't the VStack be moving as well if so?

Comment: hard to say without more code. Doesn't seem to be an environment issue tho.

Comment: Look at this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64566492/1630618)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of vacawama who linked [to a thread in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566492/swiftui-broken-explicit-animations-in-navigationview) of the question. That thread also had an answer with another [helpful link as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642367/swiftui-animation-inside-navigationview/66643096#66643096) Those were essentially the same problem as I was having here.

**Here's the short and sweet:**

It boils down to implicit vs explicit animations. In my code, here, I'm using an "explicit" animation. While using an "implicit" animation (`withAnimation()`) prevents the problem.

Apparently this may have something to do with how the `View` is being animated if the `View` is being navigated to. As was my case, I'm showing this `View` upon navigation. So the "navigation animation" was getting mixed in with my explicit animation. And, by using an implicit animation, SwiftUI is smart enough to figure out that the navigation animation is not supposed to be part of it.

**Here's the code:**

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Circle()
          .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: backgroundCircleLineWidth))
          .fill(Global.Colors.primary60)
        
        Circle()
          .trim(from: 0, to: 0.15)
          .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: foregroundCircleLineWidth, lineCap: .round))
          .fill(Global.Colors.secondary50)
          .rotationEffect(self.rotationDegree)
    }
      .frame(width: viewWidth, height: viewWidth)
      .onAppear() {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 2.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                  self.rotationDegree = .degrees(720)
              }
          }
      }
}
```

I just run the animation inside a `withAnimation()` block. And it now works as expected.

Comment: Thank you, this explains and solve the problem 

Answer (score 3):

For me this suddenly started happening out of nowhere. Hadn't changed any code, but the parent view was suddenly animating slowly. The solution for me was to wrap my animations in a `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`:

```
.onAppear {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: Double(Int.random(in: 10..<13))).repeatForever()) {
            blur = 125
        }
    }
}
```