# Swift UI animation diagonal instead horizontal

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios-animations

I'm trying to make a loading view with some animations, but instead of the RoundRectangle offset it self horizontaly as it's defined in the code, it is actually moving in diagonal.

Why is it animating in diagonal?

Here's my struct:

```
struct LoadingIndicator: View {
    let textToDisplay:String
    @State private var isLoading:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(textToDisplay)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .offset(x: 0, y: -25)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(width: 250, height: 3)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                .stroke(Color.indigo, lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 3)
                .offset(x: (isLoading ? 110 : -110), y: 0)
                .animation(.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(), value: isLoading)
        }.onAppear {
            self.isLoading = true
        }
    }
    
}
```

This is what I got:

[image]

This is what I wanted to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Are you using a NavigationView? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566492/swiftui-broken-explicit-animations-in-navigationview

Comment: Indeed it's inside a NavigationView

Comment: @aheze you are correct indeed! Just ran it on the main thread and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seing this question: [SwiftUI: Broken explicit animations in NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566492/swiftui-broken-explicit-animations-in-navigationview)

I solved my problem:

```
struct LoadingIndicator: View {
    let textToDisplay:String
    @State private var isLoading:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(textToDisplay)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .offset(x: 0, y: -25)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(width: 250, height: 3)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                .stroke(Color.indigo, lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 3)
                .offset(x: (isLoading ? 110 : -110), y: 0)
                .animation(.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(), value: isLoading)
        }.onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isLoading = true
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```